# How to create reg ex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to understand java regex and I am not sure how to approach a problem I am trying to tackle.

For basic purposes, lets say I have a list of words that are of length 4 - every word in this list is of size 4 - (only allowed lower case a-z, no command, numbers, etc) and I have a second list of 26 letters that reduce each loop iteration (first iteration 26 letters, 2nd time around 25 letters). I want to write a regex to get letters from the second list and find search for it in the first list.

For example, if I my second list has 25 letters (all the letters excepts r for example) I want my regex to be able to find a four letter word in the first list such that [a_z/except r][a_z/except r][a_z/except r][a_z/except r]. I am very new to writing regex and Java regex in particular, how could I begin this? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried so far to achieve this

Comment: Why do you want regular expressions for that? It is probably possible; but if you need two full paragraphs to describe the requirement ... I have the vague feeling that any fitting regex will be pretty complex. And yes, regexes are "dense" and "verbose"; but they are also very hard to read; and maintain over time. So, if you are talking about real production code, that will exist for a longer period of time (and not some learning assignment); then you might be better off "just coding" the solution; instead of pulling together highly complex regexes.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the second string to compile a regex as shown below. The second string has all alphabets expert 'r' as per the question.

```
    String secondString = "abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz";
    String regex = "["+secondString+"]{4}";
```

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
([a-z&&[^r]]{4})
```

In each iteration you must add the character in the brackets with the r.